# How can I create a trigger for sending an email with an alert message that goes out the 1st and 16th of every month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pretty new to Microsoft SQL and am trying to create an alert that will send an email. This alert would be set up to run on the 1st and 16th of every month. I also want to have that persons supervisor and manager included in on the alert email.

My tables are: 

 
**User Table**
UserID(pk), FirstName, LastName, GroupID(fk), Email 
**Group Table**
ID(Pk), Supervisor(pk)
**Balance Table** Balance(PK)

**to explain this:** 
User.GroupID = Group.ID 
User.UserID = Group.Supervisor

I'm having a hard time creating a query to find the email of the user's supervisor.

here is my trigger for sending out an email:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger BalanceEmail
AFTER UPDATE ON Balance
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE bal decimal(9,2); 
DECLARE useremail varchar(50); 
DECLARE supervisorEmail varchar(50); 
DECLARE NAME varchar(10); 

BEGIN

Select Balance
from BalanceTable 
into bal
where userid = :new.userid;

Select Firstname, Lastname 
From USER
into NAME
where userid = :new.userid; 

select distinct(email) 
from User
into useremail
where userid = :new.userid;

--- Can't figure out this query 
---select distinct(email)  
---from User
---into supervisorEmail 
---where userid = :new.userid and G.supervisor = T.UserID; 


IF Exists where bal > 200.00 
BEGIN 
EXEC 
@Recipients = useremail
@Profile_name = 'Balance'
@subject = ' Balance over 200'
@body =  (name + 'have accumulated' + bal + 'hours. Please contact your supervisor to schedule some time off.') 

end if;
end;
```

How can I write a syntax for sending the email out on the 1st and 16th of every month? 

 
I know I have a lot of errors right now, but please help and all is appreciated.

Comment: Triggers only file when an event occurs.  So if no one hits the table involved in the trigger nothing could happen.  What you want is a Agent to create a Job

Comment: Yep, schedule a SQL Agent Job.

Comment: ok thank you, i'll research on SQL Job and will see what I can find.

Comment: You want a Job scheduled. Not a trigger that relies on an event. MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear me you are in a mess aren't you!
Firstly you need to improve your table structures. The Balance table is seems unnecessary, your Users table probably should have a balance column. See below for a better structure as I see it. The following is a script that sets a couple of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTable (
  UserID INT, 
  FirstName VARCHAR(100), 
  LastName VARCHAR(100), 
  GroupID INT, 
  Email VARCHAR(256), 
  Balance FLOAT
)
CREATE TABLE GroupTable (
  GroupID INT, 
  GroupName VARCHAR(100), 
  GroupSupervisorID INT
)
```

Now populate the new tables with dummy data for testing:

```
INSERT GroupTable (GroupID, GroupName, GroupSupervisorID) VALUES(1, 'Group 1', 1)
INSERT GroupTable (GroupID, GroupName, GroupSupervisorID) VALUES(2, 'Group 2', 4)

INSERT UserTable (UserID, FirstName, LastName, GroupID, Email, Balance) VALUES(1, 'Anne', '', 1,  'Anne@someaddress.com', 0 )
INSERT UserTable (UserID, FirstName, LastName, GroupID, Email, Balance) VALUES(2, 'Suzy', '', 1,  'Suzy@someaddress.com', 250)
INSERT UserTable (UserID, FirstName, LastName, GroupID, Email, Balance) VALUES(3, 'Peta', '', 2,  'Peta@someaddress.com', 211)
INSERT UserTable (UserID, FirstName, LastName, GroupID, Email, Balance) VALUES(4, 'Lisa', '', 2,  'Lisa@someaddress.com', 66 )
```

As others have mentioned you need to set up a [SQL SERVER Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms189237.aspx) job that fires off on the 1st and 16th of every month. Secondly you need to set up your SQL SERVER to do emails, see [this link for sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190307.aspx)

When your SQL Agent runs it should execute a script like the following:

```
DECLARE @UserId INT
DECLARE @UserEmailRecipient VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @SupervisorEmailRecipient VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @Balance FLOAT

DECLARE UserEmail_Cursor  CURSOR 
FOR
  SELECT
    UserID
  FROM
    UserTable
  WHERE
    Balance >= 200.00


OPEN UserEmail_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM UserEmail_Cursor INTO @UserId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT
          @Name = ut.FirstName + ' ' + ut.LastName,
          @UserEmailRecipient = ut.Email,
          @Balance = ut.Balance,
          @SupervisorEmailRecipient = Supervisors.Email
      FROM
        UserTable AS ut
        JOIN GroupTable AS gt
          ON ut.GroupID = gt.GroupID
        JOIN UserTable AS Supervisors
          ON gt.GroupSupervisorID = Supervisors.UserID
      WHERE
        ut.UserID = @UserId

      -- Send User email
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @profile_name = 'DB Email Administrator', --NOTE THAT THIS MUST BE SET UP IT IS NOT SOME ARBITRARY STRING
          @recipients = @UserEmailRecipient,
          @body = @Name + ', you have accumulated' + CAST(@Balance AS VARCHAR(20)) + 'hours. Please contact your supervisor to schedule some time off.',
          @subject =  'Balance over 200' ;       

      -- Send Supervisor email
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @profile_name = 'DB Email Administrator', --NOTE THAT THIS MUST BE SET UP IT IS NOT SOME ARBITRARY STRING
          @recipients = @SupervisorEmailRecipient,
          @body = 'One of your minions, ' + @Name + 'has accumulated' + CAST(@Balance AS VARCHAR(20)) + 'hours. She will contact you to schedule some time off.',
          @subject =  'Balance over 200' ;       


      FETCH NEXT FROM UserEmail_Cursor  INTO @UserId;

   END;

CLOSE UserEmail_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE UserEmail_Cursor;
GO
```

If you have correctly set up db mail and the agent job the above script will send an email to each user and their suprvisor advising of their balance.